# C# WPF Перенос строчек в DataGrid кодом

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть некоторый код, который выводит данные из БД в ListBox.
Вид этого текста полностью генерируется кодом.
В выводе присутствуют авто собираемые таблицы.
Как сделать так, что бы текст в ячейках этих таблиц переносился?

```
Regex TabNameMatch = new Regex("TBLNAME_(.+?)_TBLNAME ");
string SMTMP = TabNameMatch.Match(kbfjdbhvdvyg.TablesFromDB[0]).Groups[1].ToString();
OutListBox.Items.Add(TabNameMatch.Match(kbfjdbhvdvyg.TablesFromDB[0]).Groups[1].ToString());
DataGrid Table = new DataGrid();
List<string> SomeTabSheets = new List<string>();
foreach (string Tabline in kbfjdbhvdvyg.TablesFromDB)
    if (Tabline.StartsWith(TabTMP))  
        SomeTabSheets.Add(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Tabline, "TBLNAME_" + SMTMP + "_TBLNAME ", string.Empty), TabTMP, string.Empty), "ENDOFLINE", string.Empty));

DataGridTextColumn dgtcft = new DataGridTextColumn();
dgtcft.Header = SomeTabSheets[0].Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
dgtcft.Binding = new Binding("firstTab");
Table.Columns.Add(dgtcft);
DataGridTextColumn dgtcst = new DataGridTextColumn();
dgtcst.Header = SomeTabSheets[0].Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
dgtcst.Binding = new Binding("secondTab");
dgtcst.ElementStyle.RegisterName("StaticResource", TextWrapping.Wrap);
Table.Columns.Add(dgtcst);
for (int i = 1; i < SomeTabSheets.Count; i++)
    Table.Items.Add(new TwoTabsTable() { firstTab = Regex.Replace(SomeTabSheets[i].Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0], "<.+?>", String.Empty), secondTab = SomeTabSheets[i].Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] });

Table.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
Table.MaxWidth = 600;
OutListBox.Items.Add(Table);
```

Это тот код, который собирает эти таблицы для вывода в ListBox

Comment: Куда переносился? Главная проблема этого кода, что он сделан "в лоб". Так как вы реализовали, никто в WPF не делает, в WPF работают с данными, а для вывода в контролы используют привязки данных. Ваш подход больше похож на Winforms. Но чтобы это исправить и привести в порядок, надо код запускать, но запустить этот участок кода нереально, так как вообще непонятно, что за контролы в интерфейсе, какие исходные данные и что должно получиться в итоге. Нужен [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: О, кажется дошло, переносился по словам чтоли?

Comment: @aepot, Знаешь, там для минимума, мне нужно скинуть, -+ весь проект.

Comment: @АнтонСтадников Стоит задуматься тогда о архитектуре проекта, ибо если для предоставления куска, вам надо скинуть весь проект, то значит у вас там все тесно завязано друг с другом, что является совершенно неверным подходом, нарушением всех возможных правил программирования. В любом случае, представьте, что вы этот огрызок кода даете первому встречному на улице, он вас поймет? Нет. Почему мы должны это понять?) В ваших интересах сделать все, чтоб мы понимали то, что вы от нас хотите, не в наших.

Comment: @aepot. Там просто суть в том, что я получаю с БД строку, и ее надо запихнуть на свое место. С запихиванием все нормально, но вот с переносом текста все грустно. Я надеялся, что есть штатный метод, который позволит переносить текст на другую строку в ячейка, при достижении ячейкой максимально допустимой ширины.